# On empty clause in columns nested path does not work in oracle 19

Tags: json, oracle

i have many query like that in oracle 12c database:

```
select query_id, name1, choice_id
from
json_table('{"queryId": "22"}', '$' error on error
columns nested path '$[*]' columns (
    query_id number path '$.queryId',
    choice_id number path '$.choiceId' DEFAULT '-1' ON EMPTY
 )
 )
;
```

has something changed?

i tested on livesql.oracle.com and it return empty value too
and it return -1 as choice_id

now we are updating to oracle 19c and all that type of query return null instead of -1

Comment: It should be raised as a ticket because it is documented and works at least in the fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/T3x8NDpH on both 18c and 21c

Comment: i tried fiddle too but they are 18 and 21 while i have 19

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/V0ol8ypI

21c return null

Comment: It returns null in 19.16 [and in 21c](https://dbfiddle.uk/YOVT2VuS). I'm not sure that's wrong though - why are you using `nested path` here, when you don't have an array? It does what you seem to expect if you do pass an array, `'[{"queryId": "22"}]'`. It isn't clear what should happen with the value you are passing.

Comment: i get packages done in that way. it's used for etherogenous array, where rows have different properties